# What are the abilities you can give your custom character?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

I just want to know what pieces give you power.

Comment: Hi Spiral Universe, some extra information would be very welcome: what are the pieces you are talking about, for example?

Comment: @Joachim in LEGO: Marvel Super Heroes you can make your own hero with LEGO Minifig parts found in the game. **Some** of those parts give your custom character powers based on the character the part is from, and some parts override powers from other parts (Ex: Wolverine claws might override fire blasts from using the Human Torch's torso, but you might retain flight from that same torso part). It's all inconsistent and weird if I remember correctly.